# Button to Cancel an Async Method (wpf - databinding comand)

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm

I'm using a pre-coded AsynchronousCommand Reference Class to invoke my method and I'd like to use the same reference to cancel that method, because this reference class already have some methods to cancel.
You can see this classes in the follow link as well:
http://pastebin.com/00eStgP6

```
public class AsynchronousCommand : CommandReference, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public AsynchronousCommand(Action action, bool canExecute = true)
            : base(action, canExecute)
        {
            Initialise();
        }

        public AsynchronousCommand(Action<object> parameterizedAction, bool canExecute = true)
            : base(parameterizedAction, canExecute)
        {
            Initialise();
        }

        private void Initialise()
        {
            cancelCommand = new CommandReference(
          () =>
          {
              IsCancellationRequested = true;
          }, true);
        }

        public override void DoExecute(object param)
        {
            if (IsExecuting)
                return;

            CancelCommandEventArgs args = new CancelCommandEventArgs() { Parameter = param, Cancel = false };
            InvokeExecuting(args);

            if (args.Cancel)
                return;

            IsExecuting = true;

            callingDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            (state) =>
            {
                InvokeAction(param);

                ReportProgress(
                  () =>
                  {
                      IsExecuting = false;

                      if (IsCancellationRequested)
                          InvokeCancelled(new CommandEventArgs() { Parameter = param });
                      else
                          InvokeExecuted(new CommandEventArgs() { Parameter = param });

                      IsCancellationRequested = false;
                  }
                );
            }
          );
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;

            if (propertyChanged != null)
                propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public void ReportProgress(Action action)
        {
            if (IsExecuting)
            {
                if (callingDispatcher.CheckAccess())
                    action();
                else
                    callingDispatcher.BeginInvoke(((Action)(() => { action(); })));
            }
        }

        public bool CancelIfRequested()
        {
            if (IsCancellationRequested == false)
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        protected void InvokeCancelled(CommandEventArgs args)
        {
            CommandEventHandler cancelled = Cancelled;

            if (cancelled != null)
                cancelled(this, args);
        }

        protected Dispatcher callingDispatcher;

        private bool isExecuting = false;

        private bool isCancellationRequested;

        private CommandReference cancelCommand;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public event CommandEventHandler Cancelled;

        public bool IsExecuting
        {
            get
            {
                return isExecuting;
            }
            set
            {
                if (isExecuting != value)
                {
                    isExecuting = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("IsExecuting");
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsCancellationRequested
        {
            get
            {
                return isCancellationRequested;
            }
            set
            {
                if (isCancellationRequested != value)
                {
                    isCancellationRequested = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("IsCancellationRequested");
                }
            }
        }

        public CommandReference CancelCommand
        {
            get { return cancelCommand; }
        }
    }
```

I'm binding the command in the view.

```
Command="{Binding ComandoProcessarArquivo}
```

And in my ViewModel:

```
private AsynchronousCommand _comandoProcessarArquivo;

public ICommand ComandoProcessarArquivo
        {
            get { return _comandoProcessarArquivo ??      (_comandoProcessarArquivo = new AsynchronousCommand(new Action(() => ProcessarArquivo()))); }
        }

private void ProcessarArquivo()
        {
    new ProcessarArquivo().Iniciar(ArquivoOrigem, ArquivoDestino, AtualizarEtapaProcesso);
}
```

So, I've tried to create the Cancel Button for more than 2 hours, please can someone give me a light :|

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this particular Async Command implementation before, and it appears to be fairly convoluted.

That said, it exposes a second CancelCommand. You did not include your Xaml for the cancellation button but the binding should look something like:

```
Command="{Binding ComandoProcessarArquivo.CancelCommand}"
```

If this command implementation is something you found (rather than a company standard) then I would recommend looking around at other options. Nito.AsyncEx has a good modern async command implementation.

Comment: Andrew, I'm working on a company software and they used this class, but I'm free to change. I've tried before to implement the cancelcommand like you said, however it didnt work :(. I'll give a look at nito.asyncex ASAP, do you have any link? Thank you mate :P